# C2676. Binary '>': 'const T' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator

Tags: c++

I have a custom List class and I want to write a method to sort items in this List. For example:

```
void ListAlgoritms<T>::Sort(List<T>& list)
{
    T temp;

    for (int i = 0; i < list.GetSize() - 1; i++)
    {
        if (list[i] > list[i + 1])
        {
            list.Swap(i, i + 1);
        }

        i--;
    }
}
```

Overloading of square brackets in List:

```
template<typename T>
const T & List<T>::operator[](int index)
{
    if (index < this->_size || index >= this->_size)
    {
        throw new std::exception("Out of array border");
    }

    ListNode<T> *cur = this->_head;
    int counter = 0;

    while (cur != nullptr)
    {
        if (counter == index)
        {
            return cur->data;
        }

        cur = cur->next;
        counter++;
    }

    return NULL;
}
```

To comapre two objects in Sort method I overload '>' and '<' in the classes that I want to add to the List. For example:

```
bool Coach::operator >(const Coach & obj) const
{
    return strlen(this->_vehicleInfo._vechicleName) > strlen(obj._vehicleInfo._vechicleName);
}

bool Coach::operator <(const Coach & obj) const
{
    return strlen(this->_vehicleInfo._vechicleName) < strlen(obj._vehicleInfo._vechicleName);
}
```

But when I try to compile the project, I have this error:

```
C2676. Binary '>': 'const T' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator.
```

But it's works good with overloading >> and << operators (input/output operators)

```
   class Coach : public PassengerVehicle
{
public:
    Coach(double fuelConsumption = 0, int maxNumberOfPersons = 0, double ticketCost = 0, const char* name = new char[10]{ "undefine" }, int countOfSections = 0);
    ~Coach();

    Coach(const Coach &coach);

public:
    void Move(double) override;
    double GetProfit() override;
    int GetCountOfSections();
    void SetCountOfSections(int count); 

    void SetHeader();
    void SetData(texttable::TextTable& t);
    Coach& operator = (Coach& obj);
    bool operator > (const Coach& obj) const;
    bool operator < (const Coach& obj) const;
    friend std::ostream & operator << (std::ostream &out, Coach& vehicle);
    friend std::istream & operator >> (std::istream &in, Coach& vehicle);

private:
    int CountOfSections;

};
```

/////////////////////////////

```
       T inputData;
    ...
std::cin >> inputData;
```

Comment: O.T.: A list has certain adventages but random access is not among of them. ;-)

Comment: Please, make a [mcve]. For that, a (to the minimum reduced) `Coach` would be needed as well as a simple call of `<` and/or `>` for two instances in `main()`. The list is either not relevant or the problem is actually not the operators of `Coach`. (A [mcve] would be perfect to sort this out.) To be sure: A [mcve] is something I can copy/paste to [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/) to reproduce your issue. (You could even add the link to your question.)

Comment: Add new informtion.

Comment: For what type do you have instanced template `List<>`?

Comment: @Scheff I define type in runtime. User can cpecify Coach or some other types wich have overloading for '>' and '<'

Comment: You oversee something essential: A template is instanced at compile time (to a concrete class). Is it a `List<PassengerVehicle>` or a `List<Coach>`, you are trying to sort?

Comment: @Scheff Yes, I try to sort List<Coach>

Comment: I'm afraid I didn't mention [mcve] often enough... :-(

Comment: Since Scheff didn't mention it enough: A [mcve], something that can be copied into an online compiler such as the ones listed in [the C++ tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%2b%2b/info), is a very useful debugging tool. You might even find your problem in the process of creating one. Without one, the chance of someone being able to help you drops considerably.